# EOF Errors in melt function pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below and i trying to convert headers that have datetimes in to row variables.

This is my dataframe.

```
CD  Data    Week    day_of_week FBM_PROCESS_NAME    FBM_USER_ID 04/09/2020 00:00    04/09/2020 00:03    04/09/2020 00:06    04/09/2020 00:09
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS1    user1   1   1   0   1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS2    user1   2   0   1   0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS3    user3   3   0   1   1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS4    user4   4   0   1   1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS5    user5   5   1   0   1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS6    user5   6   1   1   1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS7    user7   0   0   0   1
```

And my target is:

```
CD  Data    Week    day_of_week FBM_PROCESS_NAME    FBM_USER_ID variable    value
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS1    user1   04/09/2020 00:00    1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS2    user1   04/09/2020 00:00    2
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS3    user3   04/09/2020 00:00    3
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS4    user4   04/09/2020 00:00    4
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS5    user5   04/09/2020 00:00    5
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS6    user5   04/09/2020 00:00    6
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS7    user7   04/09/2020 00:00    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS1    user1   04/09/2020 00:03    1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS2    user1   04/09/2020 00:03    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS3    user3   04/09/2020 00:03    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS4    user4   04/09/2020 00:03    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS5    user5   04/09/2020 00:03    1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS6    user5   04/09/2020 00:03    1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS7    user7   04/09/2020 00:03    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS1    user1   04/09/2020 00:06    1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS2    user1   04/09/2020 00:06    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS3    user3   04/09/2020 00:06    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS4    user4   04/09/2020 00:06    0
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS5    user5   04/09/2020 00:06    1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS6    user5   04/09/2020 00:06    1
CD1 17/08/2020  34  Monday  PROCESS7    user7   04/09/2020 00:06    0
```

I using function below:

```
dftime = df_hd_data.melt(id_vars=['Data', 'Week',    'day_of_week',
        'FBM_PROCESS_NAME',   'FBM_USER_ID'], 
             value_vars=['04/09/2020 00:00', '04/09/2020 00:03',
 '04/09/2020 00:06', '04/09/2020 00:09']
```

But it always return the error below in the last line:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

could you please help me find my error?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the parentheses

```
    dftime = df_hd_data.melt(id_vars=['Data', 'Week',    'day_of_week',
        'FBM_PROCESS_NAME',   'FBM_USER_ID'], 
             value_vars=['04/09/2020 00:00', '04/09/2020 00:03',
 '04/09/2020 00:06', '04/09/2020 00:09'])
```

Comment: Resolved the first error. but now it return me the erros below. `KeyError: "The following 'value_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['2020-09-04 00:00:00', '2020-09-04 00:03:00', '2020-09-04 00:06:00', '2020-09-04 00:09:00'`  `, but the value vars that i using is exactly the sable my headers as you can see Data Week day_of_week FBM_PROCESS_NAME FBM_USER_ID 2020-09-04 00:00:00 2020-09-04 00:03:00 2020-09-04 00:06:00

Comment: Do your column names have spaces? If they do, add them to the value vars. You can either remove this spaces with `df_hd_data.columns = [column.strip() for column in df_hd_data.columns]`.

Comment: Thank you. I also get process my file using `error_bad_lines=False` that ignore all rows with erros.